# Stateful retry with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have implemented a `RetryListener` that listens for failures in a SCSt application with Kafka. I'm wondering if there's a way to pass additional information to the RetryContext and then to the retried operation.

Flow:

1. Operation fails
2. RetryListener.onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback callback, Throwable throwable) is called. <--- I want to pass additional information to the context
3. The operation is retried <--- I want to pass additional information to the retry (Possibly through the callback?)

I've been going through the source code and I know it's possible to pass a `stateful` `boolean` to `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter` but am unsure how to pass this to the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the listener thread...

`RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().setAttribute("foo", "bar");`

```
/**
 * Global variable support for retry clients. Normally it is not necessary for
 * clients to be aware of the surrounding environment because a
 * {@link RetryCallback} can always use the context it is passed by the
 * enclosing {@link RetryOperations}. But occasionally it might be helpful to
 * have lower level access to the ongoing {@link RetryContext} so we provide a
 * global accessor here. The mutator methods ({@link #clear()} and
 * {@link #register(RetryContext)} should not be used except internally by
 * {@link RetryOperations} implementations.
 * 
 * @author Dave Syer
 * 
 */
public final class RetrySynchronizationManager {
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm going down the wrong path and the `stateful` boolean isn't what I need. Is there a way to pass information to the code that is executing the retry? I need to maintain an ID across retries.

Comment: Why do you need stateful? I thought you just wanted to convey some additional information from the `@StreamListener` to the `RetryListener` and possibly vice-versa.

Comment: I think I got bogged down in the semantics of the document, and I'm not sure `stateful` is what I need. What I'm after is being able to pass more information to the retry, like an ID, so the next retry can reference the previous ID.

Comment: OK; so set the attribute in `RetryListener.open()`; access it in the stream listener using the synchronization manager; add more attributes there, if you want, so you can access them in the `onError()` method. Etc... etc...